# Replacing \s with \u00A0 with .sub() to a Word document

Tags: python, regex, docx

I want to create a/(my first) script that replaces a space behind a character with a non-breaking space (\u00A0) in a Word document, then changes the text and saves the altered document.

**tldr
Q: why does 'p' in the for loop evaluate to 'space' + character + 'space' instead of non-breaking space?**

```
#Replace a space behind an unwanted expressions with a non-breaking space from a Word document to a new Word document.
import docx, re, sys

#get document name from command line
#if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    #name = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
#doc = docx.Document(name + '.docx')
doc = docx.Document('Kajla.docx')  #used this particular file for testing, will delete this line afterwards

#regex of unwanted expressions
regex = re.compile(r'''
(\s)                  #space
([aivkszuAIVKSZU])    #unwanted char
\s                    #space
''', re.VERBOSE)

#goes through each paragraph, replaces a match and saves it
for paragraph in range(len(doc.paragraphs)):
    #keeps the space and the unwated character but replaces the last space
    p = regex.sub(r'\1\2'+'\u00A0', doc.paragraphs[paragraph].text)
    #doc.paragraphs[paragraph].text = p #commented out since it wasnt working
    #print(p)      #for testing, will delete

#saves document as a copy
#doc.save(name + '2.docx')
doc.save('Kajla2.docx')
```

Comment: Clear and concise question(s). Perhaps the multiple questions would do better split into their own posts.

Comment: `p = whatever` doesn't actually affect the document in any way. You're assigning over and over to a variable that isn't used for anything.